# Is the NULL pointer < any other pointer (except NULL)?

Tags: c, pointers

Another question about the C standard. I have tested this and I always get `NULL < ptr` true, where `ptr` is any pointer different from `NULL`. But I know that the Standard says that pointer arithmetic and comparison is only defined inside the bounds of an array. I'm just not sure if the particular comparison `NULL < ptr` is legal.

**Edit**: I have been reading K&R and I found the following quote:

> Any pointer can be meaningfully compared for equality or inequality with zero. But the behavior is undefined for arithmetic or comparisons with pointers that do not point to members of the same array.

I'm not sure if this affects the answers already given to this question. In any case, I am still unsure whether `p > NULL` is always guaranteed or not to return true, where `p` is a pointer `!=NULL`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NULL < ptr` is invalid:  a null pointer cannot be relationally compared.  To do so yields undefined behavior.

You are correct that you can only relationally compare pointers that point into the same object (either to elements in an array or subobjects of an aggregate).  Since a null pointer does not point at any object, you can't relationally compare it with anything.

Comment: Isn't NULL the special case of a pointer with value of 0?  So as long as you aren't referencing your 0 address, then NULL < ptr would always be true, but not necessarily guaranteed to be so.

Comment: @JoshPetitt:  The important thing here is that relational comparison of pointers in C is constrained to a very small set of valid scenarios.  Both operands must be pointers that point into the same aggregate, otherwise the behavior of the `<` is undefined.  So, if you have `int main() { int x, y; return &x < &y; }`, the behavior is undefined.  Since a null pointer points to no object, performing a relational comparison where either operand (or both operands!) is a null pointer yields undefined behavior.

Comment: Note however that `(uintptr_t)&x < (uintptr_t)&y` is defined, and for any given invocation of the function, it will be either 0 or 1.

Comment: @R.. only if `uintprt_t` is defined at all, which is more or less equivalent to saying that if the platform has a linear address space.

Comment: @JoshPetitt, no `NULL` and other null pointers doesn't necessarily have an internal representation that corresponds to all bits zero.

Comment: @JensGustedt: A platform does not need to have a linear address space to implement uintptr_t. The C standard defines no semantics for it other than that converting a pointer to it and back yields something that compares equal to the original value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, ok, let's reformulate, if the platform has a linearizable address space. And BTW, even if `uintptr_t` exists, I don't think that it is stated anywhere that pointer conversion to that type and integer ordering of that type must lead to something consistent.

Answer (score 3):

Only comparison with another NULL (=true) or not (=false) is defined.

NULL is *generally* defined as zero so will *generally* compare as less than, but really it's not defined